# How to set alias instead of id , i need category_id without using forloop

Tags: cakephp-3.0

```
$categoryData = $this->compCatObj->find()->select(['CompanyCategory.id', 'CompanyCategory.name','CompanyCategory.restricted'])->contain(['CompanyItems'=>['fields'=>['CompanyItems.id','CompanyItems.company_category_id','CompanyItems.name']]])->toArray();
```

Response

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "message": "List of company categories",
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Breakfast  gdfgedfgdf",
            "restricted": "no",
            "company_items": []
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Breakfast",
            "restricted": "yes",
            "company_items": []
        }

    ]
}
```

i need category_id instead of id. Is there any way to do this without using forloop.

Comment: What do you mean? 1 and 2 *are* the category ids.

Comment: yes , "id": 1  & "id": 2 are category ids..  Can we change the response key.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can do this by a small change in your code,

```
$categoryData = $this->compCatObj->find()->select(['category_id' => 'CompanyCategory.id', 'CompanyCategory.name','CompanyCategory.restricted'])->contain(['CompanyItems'=>['fields'=>['CompanyItems.id','CompanyItems.company_category_id','CompanyItems.name']]])->toArray();
```

Response

```
{
"status": "success",
"message": "List of company categories",
"data": [
    {
        "category_id": 1,
        "name": "Breakfast  gdfgedfgdf",
        "restricted": "no",
        "company_items": []
    },
    {
        "category_id": 2,
        "name": "Breakfast",
        "restricted": "yes",
        "company_items": []
    }

  ]
}
```